# Extending a theorem from bipartite graphs to tripartite hypergraphs

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory, hypergraphs

Here is a useful theorem on bipartite graphs.

**Theorem**. Let $G = (X\cup Y,E)$ be a bipartite graph with $n$ vertices in each side
and positive weights on the edges. 
If for each vertex $v \in X\cup Y$, the sum of weights of edges adjacent to $v$ is exactly $1/n$, then the graph admits a perfect matching.

*Proof*. For every integer $k \geq 1$, and for every subset of $k$ vertices in $X$, the sum of weights near them is $k/n$, so they must be adjacent to at least $k$ vertices in $Y$.
By Hall's marriage theorem, the graph admits a perfect matching.

I am looking for an analogue of this theorem on *tripartite hypergraphs*. My first attempt was:

> Let $H = (X\cup Y \cup Z,E)$ be a tripartite hypergraph with $n$ vertices in each side
>   and positive weights on the hyperedges. 
>   If for each vertex $v \in X\cup Y\cup Z$, the sum of weights of edges adjacent to $v$ is exactly $1/n$, then the graph admits a perfect matching.

But this is not correct even for $n=2$. For example, consider the hypergraph with hyperedges $(x_1,y_1,z_1),(x_2,y_2,z_1),(x_1,y_2,z_2),(x_2,y_1,z_2)$ where each hyperedge has a weight of $1/4$. The sum of weights near each edge is $1/2$, but it does not admit a perfect matching.

I conjecture that the analogous theorem requires to make one of the sets larger. For example, suppose $|X|=|Y|=n$ and $|Z|=2n$; the sum of weights is $1/n$ near each vertex in $X$ or $Y$ and $1/2n$ near each vertex in $Z$. In this case, is a perfect matching (a matching of size $n$) guaranteed to exist?